# Jquery XML Search and display results with specific user input criteria

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, regex, search

I have been searching alot and trying new things but none worked for me.

**Scenario:** User has a search form for searching files in which there are multiple checkboxes, radios, input field.

Now, user can select the search criteria i.e. search by file type(pdf, doc, image, keywords.. etc...) or by keywords(metadata) or/and by file title.

The data source is xml.

I am using ajax, regExp to match. But don't know what is needed to get the correct results and display them. May i know if:

**1. This approach is right where there is a large data(large xml with over 10,000 of entries).**

**2. what is needed to get the correct results and display them.**

I've reached so far and now I am stuck....

Thanks in advance....

**HTML**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>custom search</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/search.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>

<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="searchForm">
<div><h1>Search....</h1></div>
<form class="myform">
<div class="radio">
Please select a type of file:
<input type="radio" id="pdf" name="docbox" value="pdf">
<label for="pdf">pdf</label>
<input type="radio" id="doc" name="docbox" value="doc">
<label for="doc">doc</label>
</div><!-- Radio ends-->
<label for="searchbox">Please enter your search here</label>
<input type="text" id="searchterm" name="searchbox" placeholder="search">
<input type="submit" id="go">

<div class="keywordbox">
 <label for="keytitle"> Please search by :</label>
  <label>
<input type="checkbox" name="keytitle" value="filename" id="filename">
filename</label>

 <label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="keytitle" value="keywords" id="keywords">
   keywords</label>
  <br>
 </div>
 </form><!-- searchForm -->
<div class="timeline">

</div>
</div>

</body>
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<search>
<item>
    <filename id="pdf">John</filename>
    <keywords>Paul, John, John Paul</keywords>
</item>
<item>
    <filename id="doc">George</filename>
    <keywords>Goerge, artist, artist george</keywords>
</item>
<item>
    <filename id="pdf">Mark</filename>
    <keywords>Anthony, Mark, Anthony, Singer</keywords>
</item>
<item>
    <filename id="doc">Bryan</filename>
    <keywords>Adams, Bryan, Rockstar</keywords>
</item>
<item>
    <filename id="pdf">Westlife</filename>
    <keywords>Mylove, swear it over, </keywords>
</item>
 </search>
```

**JS**[UPDATE]

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

var filetypearray = [];  // Array for storing matched filetypes
var filenamearray = [];  // Array for storing matched filenames
var typearray = [];// Array for Selected type results i.e. pdf or doc
var keywordarray = [];   // Array for matched keywords

  $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "search.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXML,
        //error:function(){alert("Error: Something went wrong");}

     });

   function parseXML(xml){

$('#go').click(function(){

var searchFor = $("input#searchterm").val();                          
   // TextInput for search 
var catType = $("input[name=docbox]:checked").val();    // type of radio checked  
   pdf or doc
     var catType2 = $("input[name='keytitle']:checked").val();  // keyword checkbox
var errMsg = '';




            $(xml).find('search item').map(function() {
                var filename = $(this).find('filename').text();         
                var filetypetext = 
         $(this).find('filename').attr('id');   
                var type = $(this).find('filename').attr('id');
                var keyword = $(this).find('keywords').text();
                var title = $(this).find('filename').text();

                var reg = new RegExp(searchFor, "gi");               
                                        //Reg for TextInput for search 
                var regcattype = new RegExp(catType, "gi");         
                                       //Reg for radio checked for search 
                var regkey = new RegExp(catType2, "gi");            
                              //Reg for keyword checked for search 


      /////////////////// Condition for text input search only//////////////////////    

    if($('input#keywords').is(':not(:checked)') &&    
       $('input#pdf').is(':not(:checked)') && filename == searchFor) 

    // Checking Input string matched the Filename
    {

            var filenamesrch = filename.match(reg);
            for(i=0; i<filenamesrch.length; i++){
                    filenamearray.push(filenamesrch); 
                    filetypearray.push(filetypetext);
                    keywordarray.push(keyword);
                    }

    $('.timeline').html('Found <b>'+filenamearray.length+'</b> results in 

      Filenames: <i>Filename</i> <b>'+filenamearray+'</b> with type as 
           <b>'+filetypearray+'</b> and keywords as <b>'+keywordarray+'</b>');


    }


else if(($('input#keywords').is(':not(:checked)') && filename != searchFor)){
    $('.timeline').html('No results');

    }


   /////////////////// Condition for Keyword search only ////////////////////////////// 

 else if ($('input#keywords').is(':checked') && keyword == searchFor){

                var kewordsrch = keyword.match(reg);
                for(j=0; j<kewordsrch.length; j++){
                    keywordarray.push(kewordsrch);
                    filetypearray.push(filetypetext);
                    filenamearray.push(filename);
                    }

$('.timeline').html('Found <b>'+keywordarray.length+'</b> results in Keywords: 
   <i>keyword</i> <b>'+keywordarray+'</b> with type as <b>'+filetypearray+'</b> and 
    Filename as <b>'+filenamearray+'</b>');
     }

     else if(($('input#keywords').is(':checked') && searchFor == '')){
    $('.timeline').html('Please enter a keyword to search');

    }

else if(($('input#keywords').is(':checked') && keyword != searchFor)){
    $('.timeline').html('No results');

    }

       /////////////////// Condition for Filetype pdf search only ///////////////////       

    if(searchFor != ''){ 
            if ($('input#pdf').is(':checked') && filetypetext ==  
       catType){

                if (filename == searchFor){

                //$(':text').attr('disabled', true);
                var typesrch = filetypetext.match(regcattype);
                for(k=0; k<typesrch.length; k++){
                    typearray.push(typesrch);
                    keywordarray.push(keyword);
                    filenamearray.push(filename);
            }
                }
            //alert(resultarray)
    $('.timeline').html('Found <b>'+typearray.length+'</b> results in Types: 
     <i>type</i> <b>'+typearray+'</b> with filename(s) as <b>'+filenamearray+'</b> and 
        keywords as <b>'+keywordarray+'</b>');

    }

          /////////////////// Condition for Filetype doc search only /////////////////  


    else if ($('input#doc').is(':checked') && filetypetext == catType){

                if (filename == searchFor){
                //$(':text').attr('disabled', true);

                var typesrch = filetypetext.match(regcattype);
                alert(typesrch.length)
                for(k=0; k<typesrch.length; k++){
                    typearray.push(typesrch);
                    keywordarray.push(keyword);
                    filenamearray.push(filename);

            }
            $('.timeline').html('Found <b>'+typearray.length+'</b> 
           results in Types: <i>type</i> <b>'+typearray+'</b> with filename(s) as 
            <b>'+filenamearray+'</b> and keywords as <b>'+keywordarray+'</b>');

                }
            //alert(resultarray)

    }
    }
        });

    });
   }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

- Your script has syntax error, check with Firebug or IE Developer tools and fix them.
- I don't think you are using Find as intended.  Find will "Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector, jQuery object, or element".
- You may want to consider the following solution:

-> filter filename or keywords elements based on user selection (using find)

-> while looping match the element text value for the search keyword

-> add the matched items to an array

-> loop through the array and display the results to the user